# find the number of ways you can form a string on size N, given an unlimited number of 0s and 1s

Tags: string, algorithm

The below question was asked in the **atlassian company online test** ,I don't have test cases , this is the below question I took from  this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/atlassian-interview-experience-on-campus-august-2020/)

```
find the number of ways you can form a string on size N, given an unlimited number of 0s and 1s. But
    you cannot have D number of consecutive 0s and T number of consecutive 1s. N, D, T were given as inputs,
```

**Please help me on this problem,any approach how to proceed with it**

My approach for the above question is simply I applied recursion and tried for all possiblity and then I memoized it using hash map
But it seems to me there must be some combinatoric approach that can do this question in less time and space? for debugging purposes I am also printing the strings generated during recursion, **if there is flaw in my approach please do tell me**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

unordered_map<string,int>dp;
int recurse(int d,int t,int n,int oldd,int oldt,string s)
{

    if(d<=0)
      return 0;
    if(t<=0)
      return 0;
    cout<<s<<"\n";
     if(n==0&&d>0&&t>0)
      return 1;
    string h=to_string(d)+" "+to_string(t)+" "+to_string(n);

    if(dp.find(h)!=dp.end())
     return dp[h];
    int ans=0;
    ans+=recurse(d-1,oldt,n-1,oldd,oldt,s+'0')+recurse(oldd,t-1,n-1,oldd,oldt,s+'1');
    return dp[h]=ans;
}
int main() 
{
    int n,d,t;
    cin>>n>>d>>t;
    dp.clear();
    cout<<recurse(d,t,n,d,t,"")<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your approach is sensible, although the code can be significantly improved: using an array rather than a hashmap, and recursion replaced by iteration. Not to mention the #define stuff at the start: not sure where you learnt this, but in any commercial setting stuff like this would be considered very poor style.

Comment: I also note that your use of the string `s` and the way you append to it results in a lot of string copies, increasing your code's complexity. Note that the strings you output aren't even complete because of your hashing.

Comment: @PaulHankin actually i wrote define statements because it saves time during the test

Comment: @PaulHankin  **** I am printing string only for debugging purposes , like if anyone want to analyse my code then it woule be easier for him***

Comment: @PaulHankin I removed them

Answer (score 4):

You are right, instead of generating strings, it is worth to consider combinatoric approach using dynamic programming (a kind of).

"Good" sequence of length `K` might end with `1..D-1` zeros or `1..T-1` of ones.

To make a good sequence of length `K+1`, you can add zero to all sequences except for `D-1`, and get `2..D-1` zeros for the first kind of precursors and `1` zero for the second kind

Similarly you can add one to all sequences of the first kind, and to all sequences of the second kind except for `T-1`, and get `1` one for the first kind of precursors and `2..T-1` ones for the second kind

Make two tables

```
Zeros[N][D] and Ones[N][T]
```

Fill the first row with zero counts,  except for `Zeros[1][1] = 1, Ones[1][1] = 1`

Fill row by row using the rules above.

```
Zeros[K][1] = Sum(Ones[K-1][C=1..T-1])
for C in 2..D-1:
    Zeros[K][C] = Zeros[K-1][C-1]
Ones[K][1] = Sum(Zeros[K-1][C=1..T-1])
for C in 2..T-1:
    Ones[K][C] = Ones[K-1][C-1]
```

Result is sum of the last row in both tables.

Also note that you really need only two active rows of the table, so you can optimize size to `Zeros[2][D]` after debugging.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the rules of Ones?

Comment: @Yash Shah They are symmetrical - added.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using dynamic programming. I'll give a recursive solution to the same. It'll be similar to generating a binary string.

States will be:

- `i`: The ith character that we need to insert to the string.
- `cnt`: The number of consecutive characters before `i`
- `bit`: The character which was repeated `cnt` times before `i`. Value of bit will be either 0 or 1.

Base case will: Return 1, when we reach n since we are starting from 0 and ending at n-1.

Define the size of dp array accordingly. The time complexity will be `2 x N x max(D,T)`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int dp[1000][1000][2];

int n, d, t;
int count(int i, int cnt, int bit) {
    if (i == n) {
        return 1;
    }

    int &ans = dp[i][cnt][bit];
    if (ans != -1) return ans;
    ans = 0;
    if (bit == 0) {
        ans += count(i+1, 1, 1);
        if (cnt != d - 1) {
            ans += count(i+1, cnt + 1, 0);
        }
    } else {
        // bit == 1
        ans += count(i+1, 1, 0);
        if (cnt != t-1) {
            ans += count(i+1, cnt + 1, 1);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

    
signed main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false), cin.tie(nullptr);

    cin >> n >> d >> t;
    
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof dp);
    cout << count(0, 0, 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```